# pthread_cond_signal from multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

Let's imagine there is a thread which calls `pthread_cond_wait` and waits for signals:

```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
         .....
   while(run) 
   {
      do {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&m);
      } while(!got_signal);
      got_signal = false;
      do_something();
   }
```

And there are multiple threads which are supposed to deliver signals:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
got_signal = true;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

Is this solution safe enough? What will happen if multiple threads send signals? Does `m` mutex suffice to guarantee all signals are serialized and won't be lost?

Comment: Your loop is broken, calling `pthread_cond_wait` even if `got_signal` is already true. Also, your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "all signals"? It sounds like you have some fairly significant misunderstandings about how condition variables work. A condition variable is stateless -- if you have signals that can have state, your code has to implement that state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted, the only place where threads are allowed to call `pthread_cond_signal()` is when they can acquire `m`, and that can only happen when your waiting thread is blocked on `pthread_cond_wait()`.

However, it might happen that two signaling threads acquire the mutex after each other, before the waiting thread is woken up and can acquire the mutex. In that case you'll lose the second signal (and any further signals that might arrive after that, before the waiting thread runs), since your waiting thread can only "see" that it has been signaled, but not how many times this has happened.

To make sure that you don't lose any signals, you could use a counter instead of your `got_signal` flag:

Waiting thread:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
     .....
while(run) 
{
   while(signal_count == 0) {
     pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&m);
   } 
   --signal_count;
   do_something();
}
```

Signaling threads:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
++signal_count;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
```

(Also note that I've exchanged the `do...while`loop with a `while` loop, to make sure that `pthread_cond_wait()` isn't called if there's still an unprocessed signal left.)

Now, if multiple threads end up signaling straight after each other, `signal_count` will become more than one, which will cause the waiting thread to run its `do_something()` multiple times instead of just once.

Comment: And what should I do if I have a memory region with data which should be passed with signal to the handler thread? I need another one mutex, do I?

Comment: @olegst I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. But if you want to pass data from your signaling threads to your waiting thread, you need some way to make sure that that data is not made inconsistent by simultaneous accesses by multiple threads (as with all other data). In most cases the easiest way is to just make sure that the signaling thread doesn't modify any data that has already been sent of. For instance by either just giving the waiting thread a copy of the data, or by sending a pointer to some data, and letting the waiting thread take care of cleaning that data when done.